# How to collect IDs and group them comma separated from multiple connected tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull IDs and display them comma separated from multiple connected tables, example and structure below, I think so I must use concat and group by but not quite sure how?

table_1

```
ID  NAME
--  -----
 1  Test1
 2  Test2
```

table_2

```
ID  TABLE_1_ID  Name
--  ----------  --------
 1           1  abc
 2           1  abcd
 3           1  abcde
 4           2  abcdef
 5           2  abcdefg
 6           2  abcdefgh
```

And I would like to get result:

```
Test1 = abc,abcd,abce
Test2 = abcdef, abcdefg, abcdefgh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

```
select table_1.NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(table_2.NAME) 
from table_1 inner join table_2 
on table_1.ID=table_2.TABLE_1_ID 
group by table_1.ID
```